# Retrieve submitted PDF form on server

Tags: c#, pdf, model-view-controller, acrobat

I created a PDF Form with a submit button which sends it to my website, that processes it and stores it for later usage.

On my website, i would like to take the POSTed pdf, and save it. However, I can't find how to convert to incoming stream back to a PDF.

This is the code i currently have

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostPDF()
{
    using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        var fdfStream = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    ...
    return "Form submitted successfully!";
}
```

other things i tried were receiving an httpPostedFileBase and a byte[], like so :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostPDF(HttpPostedFileBase file)

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostPDF(byte[] file)
```

both of which were empty results.

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase` should be the right option.. check this blog about file upload in MVC  http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/8/uploading_and_returning_files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should do the job.

```
        HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
        if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }
        var parts = await request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
        Stream inputStream = null;
        string fname = null;

        foreach (var part in parts.Contents)
        {
            string dispoName = part.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name;
            if (dispoName.Equals("\"inputFile\""))
            {
                fname = part.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
                inputStream = await part.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            }
        }

        if (inputStream == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```